# How to hardcode key-value option pairs in select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't find anywhere a tutorial on how to hardcode HTML inside of select tag.

All I need is this:

```
<select name="cron[day]">
 <option value='0'>Sunday</option>
 <option value='1'>Monday</option>
 <option value='2'>Tuesday</option>
 <option value='3'>Wednesday</option>
 ...
</select>
```

Don't feel like making a special table for this. Or should I?

Comment: I wouldn't create a new table, you could create a collection that stores each day of the week and pass it to a select helper.
`<%= select( "payment", "id", { "Sunday" => "0", "Monday" => "1"}) %>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no need to create a table.  It will look something like:

```
select "cron", "day", [[ "Sunday", 0 ], [ "Monday", 1 ], ["Tuesday", 2], [etc..]]
```

It would probably be better to stick the options in a helper, rather than having them site in your view.

Comment: thanks. it works. one more quick question. how do I access the data after it was submitted to the controller? is it something like params[:cron[:day]] ?

Comment: oh, never mind - I got it: params[:cron][:day] . thanks again